# k means and elbow method produces different graph for same data and same center.

Tags: r, k-means

I am trying to find optimal cluster size from eblow graph.
Problem is every time I run the code it produces different graph.

```
    par(mfrow=c(2,2))
    for(i in 1:4){
      data <- read.csv(file = "C:/Users/sd0298/Desktop/data.csv", header =  TRUE)
      wss <- (nrow(data)-1)*sum(apply(data,2,var))
      for (i in 2:15) {
        wss[i] <- sum(kmeans(data, centers=i, iter.max = 500, nstart = 1, algorithm  = "Lloyd" , trace =  TRUE)$withinss)
      }
      plot(1:15, wss, type="b", xlab="Number of Clusters", ylab="Within groups sum of squares", main="SSE vs Cluster levels",cex.axis = 0.8)

    }
```

[image]
Also everytime when I try to plot cluster for same center and with same data it produces different graph.

```
    par(mfrow=c(2,2))
    for(i in 1:4){
      data <- read.csv(file = "C:/Users/sd0298/Desktop/data.csv", header =  TRUE)
      wss <- (nrow(data)-1)*sum(apply(data,2,var))
      km <- kmeans(data, centers=4, iter.max = 500, nstart = 1, algorithm  = "Lloyd" , trace =  TRUE)  
      clusplot(data, km$cluster, color=TRUE, shade=T, span=T, col.p = c("#666666"),   lines=0 ,plotchar=F,  sub = "" ,main = "", labels=5)            
    }
```

[image]

Can any one please tell me what is going wrong and tell me how to reproduce same cluster when center and data is not changing .

Comment: This is to be expected, as the result of `kmeans` has a random start. You could probably help the function by specifying group means in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making the following call to the `R` `kmeans()` function:

```
km <- kmeans(data, centers=4, iter.max = 500, nstart = 1, algorithm  = "Lloyd" , trace =  TRUE)
```

The [Wikipedia page for Lloyd's k-means algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyd%27s_algorithm) states the following:

> Lloyd's algorithm starts by an initial placement of some number k of point sites in the input domain. In mesh smoothing applications, these would be the vertices of the mesh to be smoothed; in other applications **they may be placed at random**, or by intersecting a uniform triangular mesh of the appropriate size with the input domain.

R's `kmeans` is using random initial conditions. The `nstart` parameter controls how many random initializations are tried. In other words, if you run Lloyd's algorithm a number of times, your resulting clusters likely will not be exactly the same.

However, you can view this non-deterministic behavior as an opportunity for you to validate the accuracy of the clusters.  If you run Lloyd's several times, and you keep getting similar clusters, then this would imply that the clusters are meaningful. **If running k-means multiple times yields very different results, it indicates that they are not reliable.**